# How to compare datetime row objects in pyspark

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe (beaconsDF) with a column normalized_date :

```
+--------+--------------------+--------------------+
|isActive|             company|     Normalized_Date|
+--------+--------------------+--------------------+
|    true|[593b0d9f3f21f9dd...|09/25/2018 00:00:...|
|    true|[593b0d9f3f21f9dd...|11/29/2017 00:00:...|
|    true|[593b0d9f3f21f9dd...|04/01/2019 00:00:...|
|    true|[593b0d9f3f21f9dd...|09/25/2018 00:00:...|
|    true|[593b0d9f3f21f9dd...|11/20/2018 00:00:...|
|    true|[593b0d9f3f21f9dd...|09/25/2018 00:00:...|
|    true|[593b0d9f3f21f9dd...|01/04/2019 00:00:...|
|    true|[593b0d9f3f21f9dd...|01/04/2019 00:00:...|
+--------+--------------------+--------------------+
```

And I want to filter it when the date equals the normalized_date in this simple dataframe (calendarDF2):

```
+--------------------+
|     Normalized_Date|
+--------------------+
|11/28/2017 00:00:...|
+--------------------+
```

I figured these few lines of code would work:

```
tempRow = calendarDF2.take(1)
beaconsDF = beaconsDF.filter(beaconsDF.Normalized_Date == tempRow)
```

But I am getting a long error with these lines in them:

> py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o214.equalTo.
>       : java.lang.RuntimeException: Unsupported literal type class java.util.ArrayList [[11/28/2017 00:00:00 AM]]

I think my issue lies in the formatting of the dates since I am really confused on the different types of formatting. I printed values from both dataframes to compare them and got this:

```
[Row(Normalized_Date=u'11/28/2017 00:00:00 AM')]  
[Row(Normalized_Date=u'04/01/2019 00:00:00 AM')]
```

which looks like it should be comparing them correctly, right? My issue could also have to do with how I am comparing them. I saw somewhere that I may need to use 3 equal signs? I tried this and it didn't work. I also tried making the tempRow a literal but that didn't work. Any idea here?

EDIT: I would also like to filter by less than or equal tempRow date as well in the future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `collect` which returns a `list` and the element extracted from it can be used for comparison. As of now, you are comparing a `list` with a scalar value and hence the error.

```
tempRow = calendarDF2.collect()[0]['Normalized_Date']
beaconsDF = beaconsDF.filter(beaconsDF.Normalized_Date == tempRow)
```

Comment: Unfortunately that resulted in the same error as before

Comment: That worked! How will '<=' or '>=' change the filtering? They seem to change it but not in the way expected

Comment: you should convert them to `datetime` type for `<=` and `>=` comparisons, provided they are not `datetime` to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to using `collect` to get the *normalized_date* from the DF, I would also suggest using the module datetime with a defined schema for this comparison:

```
import datetime as dt

format = '%m/%d/%y %I:%M:%S %p'

calendar_date = calendarDF2.collect()[0]['Normalized_Date']
normalized_date = dt.datetime.strptime(calendar_date, format)

beaconsDF = beaconsDF.filter(dt.datetime.strptime(beaconsDF.Normalized_Date) == normalized_date)
```

Comment: I am getting the error 'TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be string, not Column', how can I fix this?